# Test explorer in VS2019 shows "No source available" for specflow tests

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, specflow

In vs2019 test explorer shows "No source available" for my specflow tests, so double click will not end up going to the actual specflow test (feature file).
Those unittests are generated through the "Specflow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" nuGet package.
The feature.cs files are ignored by Git and are not part of my project file. I am able to run them and after build they are discoverable (through NUnit 3 Test adapter visual studio extension).

I've tried numerous solutions, as in:
- upgrading to sdk-style project (see https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1457#issuecomment-491497035)
- creating whole new project (full framework)

Any help would be appreciated! Thnx in advance.

Comment: Since SpecFlow 3 generates the test code at build time, and the feature.cs files are not included in the project what you are experiencing is the expected behavior.

Comment: @GregBurghardt - the previous behavior (when using SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator custom tool) was for double-clicking the Test Explorer window to navigate to the associated Gherkin - was this behavior intentionally removed, or is this an unintended side effect of using the "Generation" package rather than the custom tool??

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue. With over 3,000 tests in our repository, it is extremely inconvenient to have to track down test failures in the file system. It was really convenient to just double-click on the scenario and navigate to the Gherkin. It would be nice if there were a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the expired license of Resharper was the reason of this issue. I clicked the button **Start evaluation period** and then restart VS.

Answer (score 0):

Adding [Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk/17.5.0?_src=template) in the test project and restarting Visual Studio fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, restarting VS (2022) solved the issue.  Didn't have to change anything in code.